# Possibilty of setting the value of variable __name__ when executing a script

Tags: python

In python, when a script is executed, the variable `__name__` is set the `'main'`. Is it possible to make the value of the variable `__name__` to something else while executing the script. ***This will allow for a more dynamic script without the need to pass and parse arguments.***

For example, something like this:-

python script a.py

```
def fun1():
 ....
....
if __name__ == 'abc':
  <do something>

if __name__ == 'xyz':
  <do something else>

if __name__ == '__main__':
  <do something default>
```

And then calling the script as `python a.py <set __name__>`

Comment: Why use `__name__` for this purpose instead of just defining your own variable?

Comment: Ok, souds reasonable, can you please provide an example implementation; you may make the implementation as answer to this question.

Comment: I am not sure why not use arguments for this purpose. Using `__name__` just does not seem right.

Comment: @danyroza IMO it's just more convinient and more understandable code. I may be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try using the name of the script?  Look at `sys.argv[0]` (and run `os.path.basename` on it - or use pathlib)

The `__name__` variable is really python's own variable and is set differently depending on what is being run or included so not best not subvert it.

This used to be an old shell trick where you would link a name to a script and then use the name as if it was a default argument.

```
$ cat > myfile.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
$ chmod a+x myfile.py
$ ./myfile.py
./myfile.py
$ python myfile.py
myfile.py
$ ln -s myfile.py anothername
$ ./anothername
./anothername
```

Comment: I am not sure how sys.argv[0] will help, but yes, if the script is run as python a.py xyz, then sys.argv[1] will get you the value 'xyz'

Comment: See example added to my answer.   sys.argv[0] is the command path name (so will include the path you used to invoke the file.  So you need to munge it to get the name eg with os.path.basename

Comment: Yes, may be good approach for some situation, but for my case i have answered my own question, following your approach,

Answer (score 0):

sys.argv can be used, and below can serve the need.

```
sys.argv 
    def fun1():
     ....
    ....
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "abc":
      <do something>
    
    # or use pydash _
    if _.get(sys.argv, "[1]") == 'xyz':
      <do something else>
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      <do something default>
```

Follows from sys.argv approach by @Andrew

Comment: Suggestion for you:   If you want to pass arguments then have a look at argparse - its part of the standard library.   Even for a simple set of arguments it will make it easier for you.  Plus you will get automatic help for the usage.  ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html )